# insert into NedB boolean value without quotation marks

Tags: node.js, express, nedb

I have a NedB database which I'm trying to insert some new data into that I retrieve from HTML form, this is my function to insert new.

```
addEntry(name,desc,ingred,allergy,cat,aval,price){
        var entry = {
            Name: name,
            Description: desc,
            Ingerdients: ingred.split(','),
            Allergy: allergy.split(','),
            Category: cat,
            Availability: aval,
            price: price
        }
        this.db.insert(entry, function(err,doc) {
            if(err)
            {
                console.log("error inserting document",subject);
            }
            else{
                console.log('Meal Added Successfully');
            }
        })
    }
```

My problem is that the `Availability` is a boolean value, yet it's added in the database with quotation marks. For example: 'true' instead of true and 'false' instead of false, how can I fix this?

Comment: You can convert it to a boolean: `avalBool = (aval === "true")`.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on where to do this conversion? inside the entry array?

Comment: See my answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the parameter `aval` is a string, you could convert it to a boolean:

```js
var entry = {
  Name: name,
  Description: desc,
  Ingerdients: ingred.split(','),
  Allergy: allergy.split(','),
  Category: cat,
  Availability: aval === "true",
  price: price
}
```

But I am surprised that the database accepts a string value where it should expect a boolean. Doesn't it give you an error message?

Comment: it worked perfectly now thank you. I was surprised as well that it accepted it and tried many times to see how it got passed but didn't manage to know